# How to from top that replaces status bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

In React Native iOS, I would like to slide in and out a `<View/>` -- assuming it is implemented as such-- like the following pictures.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad this is the question

Comment: I haven't done that before. But I have some ideas and I'll look into it.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Excellent, really looking forward to it! Still no luck on my end

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Just checking in to see if you had the chance. Thanks Ahmed!

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the result:

[image]

Here's the full code to make it work.  It will not work on RNPlay because zIndex is not supported in the version they have.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';

class playground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       slideAnimation: new Animated.Value(22),
     };
   }

  _showNotification() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true, 'slide');

    Animated.timing(
      this.state.slideAnimation,
      {toValue: 0, duration: 300}
    ).start();
  }

  _hideNotification() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false, 'slide');

    Animated.timing(
      this.state.slideAnimation,
      {toValue: 22, duration: 300}
    ).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
           barStyle="default"
         />
        <Animated.View style={[styles.notification, {top: this.state.slideAnimation}]}>
          <Text style={styles.notificationText}>This is a notification</Text>
        </Animated.View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#D1EEFC" style={styles.button} onPress={()=> { this._showNotification() }}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Show Notification
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#D1EEFC" style={styles.button} onPress={()=> { this._hideNotification() }}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Hide Notification
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF', //This is important to hide the notification, because it is actually behind it
    marginTop: 22, //This will make a gap of the same height in the top, so that the notification can slide in it.
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: '#D1EEFC',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 22,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#007AFF'
  },
  notification: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 22, //Move the notification downwards to setup the scene.
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 22, //Make it the same height as the status bar
    zIndex: 0, //This is what makes the notification benhind the container
  },
  notificationText: {
    color: 'yellow',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 11,
    marginTop: 4
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('playground', () => playground);
```

---

### UPDATE

I've managed to make the masking concept work by wrapping the notification inside a view with the style overflow: 'hidden'.  The container is set to height: 22.  So if the notification moves even 1pt, it will look as if the notification is sliding-in the background.

**Here's the result:**

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Animated,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

class playground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       slideAnimation: new Animated.Value(22),
     };
   }

  _showNotification() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true, 'slide');

    Animated.timing(
      this.state.slideAnimation,
      {toValue: 0, duration: 300}
    ).start();
  }

  _hideNotification() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false, 'slide');

    Animated.timing(
      this.state.slideAnimation,
      {toValue: 22, duration: 300}
    ).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./img/splash.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} resizeMode='cover' />
        <StatusBar
           barStyle="default"
         />
        <View style={styles.notificationContainer}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.notification, {top: this.state.slideAnimation}]}>
            <Text style={styles.notificationText}>This is a notification</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#D1EEFC" style={styles.button} onPress={()=> { this._showNotification() }}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Show Notification
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#D1EEFC" style={styles.button} onPress={()=> { this._hideNotification() }}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Hide Notification
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 22,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF88',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000000'
  },
  notificationContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 22,
    overflow: 'hidden' //This is the magic trick to do the masking.
  },
  notification: {
    backgroundColor: '#00000088',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 22,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 22,
  },
  notificationText: {
    color: 'yellow',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 11,
    marginTop: 4
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('playground', () => playground);
```

Comment: Also, please fix the grammar on that validation message. It should say "You forgot __to__ choose your payment method".

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Sorry I was busy and finally got around to it today. First of all, after the notification appears, after some time, I would want it to automatically disappear on its own without  being called. What would be the right approach to it? Lastly, I have an image right under the status bar, so setting the `marginTop: 22` on a body pushes the image down, which I do not want. Would there be a work around it? If I don't do `marginTop:22` the status bar slides up, but the notification doesn't show. Assuming it is because the notification is under the image? Updated original post. Thanks

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad checking in just in case you missed my previous comment. Please let me know. Thanks Ahmed

Comment: @JoKo You could play around with using views and zIndex to achieve your goal. I can't really help you without seeing your code.  Setup a repo with a reproduction of the issue, and I'll hopefully be able to help you out.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Definitely and did play around as much as I possibly could but still no luck. Here is the code in gist: https://gist.github.com/jaewonch/ffb418ab223b45d599a343718bdcb68b . I am using `react-native-swiper` and you would just have to provide any image in place of testImage1 in `source={'../img/testImage1.jpg'}`. Really appreciate it Ahmed.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Hey Ahmed! Just checking in to see if you had the chance to take a look. Please let me know. I am just exhausted out on how to get this figured out... Thanks again!

Comment: @JoKo I'll look into it. I'm sorry I've been busy the past few days

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad No worries! Really appreciate it Ahmed. Looking forward to it!

Comment: @JoKo The only way I see it can be done is by using a view mask. The current view doesn't support masking, so you have to create your own component or to find a component that someone created.  The problem is that I was relying on the background to have a gap of 22 height, and on the notification being behind the background in z-axis.  This trick will not work with your end goal.  I'd suggest to just replace the animations value to -22 instead of 22, and keeping the z-index at 1. it will safe you time & effort, and it looks good enough.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad For some reason I didn't get a notification for the last comment. Just saw your recent comment notification! You are simply amazing. Your expertise is unmatched! Will give it a try in a few days because I'm currently away from my main computer. Just a quick question, I'm sure it would work fine with the `<Swiper/>` as well, correct? Can't thank you enough Ahmed! I will in fact just make this a bounty, just cause you deserve it.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad I changed it to bounty but currently telling me that I need to wait 23 hours to award it. Will do so right away.

Comment: @JoKo It will work on probably anything. Notice that since I've declared the image before the notification, it's showing. If you have the swiper AFTER the notification, you have to change the index of the notification so it appears above. I believe that react native stacks elements in z-axis as you go down, the most upper elements are also the most behind, and vice versa.

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad Noted and bounty awarded. Thank you so much again Ahmed. Haven't had to chance to try it out yet, but will do as soon as possible and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it.

Utilize a `<View>` which is positioned absolutely. You would want the position styles to be like this:

```
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
left: 0,
height: 20
```

Then inside the view you would want an `Animated` element, either a View or Text element. You would want that nested, animated view to start positioned "off screen" in your top view, and then in the `componentWillMount` method of your component, set the text to animate from below the view to showing in the view. That will give you the sliding in effect for your text. Here is where you can learn more about the Animated library: [Animated RN Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html)

Finally, it looks like you also want the status bar to hide simultaneously, so you would need to set it hidden and animate that action. That can easily be done, check the RN Docs for `StatusBar`

If you have troubles, post some code in your question and I can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Appreciate the response. A few questions. First of all, when you mentioned start positioned 'off screen' in my top view, are you referring to it appearing from the bottom of the status bar? Because the `<View/>` appears from the bottom of the status bar and pushes up the status bar "off the screen", and that's what I am trying to achieve. If so how can I hide the `<View/>` below the status bar? Also could you elaborate on what text is? And lastly, the status bar just doesn't disappear. It just gets pushed up, "off the screen". And after some time, it appears & pushes down the view

Comment: If you check out the `Animated` library, you can make an `<Animated.Text>` element that is also positioned absolutely WITHIN the view at height 20, then change its position as it loads.

Comment: This library isn't exactly what you need, but if you look through the source code you can see how they do theirs and then modify yours as needed 

https://github.com/KBLNY/react-native-message-bar

Comment: I made the attempt and updated the original post with edit. Any guidance or insight as to how I should go about from there?

Comment: Please let me knows. Been stuck on this for days.

Comment: You might want to look into using an interpolation in your `Animated.View` styles rather than the transforms. Something similar to this.

`top: this.state.offset.interpolate({
          
inputRange: [0, 100],

          outputRange: [0, -44],

          extrapolate: 'clamp',

       }),`

Where your input range would be your 'toValue' in your code. Check this link for more information: http://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/api/ANIMATED_INTERPOLATION.html