# In React-Native Buttons are not clickable when I applied slide up animation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-animations

I am creating a view. Inside view there are some buttons and all buttons are clickable. I created those view . working fine all buttons are clickable though.

Now my requirement is that view should have slide up animation. so I searched a little and found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117599/how-to-slide-view-in-and-out-from-the-bottom-in-react-native). Modified my code as per requirements and animation was working fine.

**But the problem is after animation my buttons are not clickable any more.**

Please help me

1. I Checked on iOS simulator it was working fine, button was clickable though
2. But I checked on Android(Physical device) it was not clickable
3. When I removed animation it was working on both iOS Simulator and Android device.

**Please help me how can I resolve that issue. Want to Make button clickable even after slide up animations**

Let me know in case you want to view code

Comment: Can you setup a snack so that I can see the issue? (https://snack.expo.io/)