# Vertical slide View in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to do vertical slide View from bottom to top as in the screenshot below, I need to pull View, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe there is some kind of library?
[image]

Comment: Check these link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117599/how-to-slide-view-in-and-out-from-the-bottom-in-react-native  https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use react-native-sliding-up-down-panel for this..
here is git link:-- https://github.com/Abhijeet-Ashapure/react-native-sliding-up-down-panel
or if you want some custom animation panel go for animation api or you may check react native PanResponder to make custom touch responding view.

To get your image like effect
you can check react-native-modalize library..